# Cut single string in parts using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

having a string like these

**1-2-3**

**1-2**

Using javascript How can I cut them so I can get the numbers separately like this

1

2

3

Comment: Use the `split()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .split() method returns an array of strings separated by a specified character.

```js
const str = '1-2-3';
const newStr = str.split('-');
console.log(newStr);
```